# how do i change name of menu item (Partner Ledger)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

Could any one help me to change the name of the menu called `Partner Ledger` in `accounting->Reports->PDF Reports-->Partner Ledger`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto `Settings -> Technical -> UserInterface -> MenuItems`
2. Search Partner Ledger
3. Rename the menuitems name.
   Thanks

Comment: This is good but only if he wants to do this for one instance of Odoo, no need to code and upgrade just update the name of the menu this why Odoo is one of the best framework

Comment: thanks but after changing if you clicked it will open a printing report still called Partner Ledger

Answer (score 1):

You can use `menuitem` tag with the same `id` (use external id) and do not forget to specify its parent menu (if there is one), because the menu looses his parent after upgrading the module:

```
<menuitem name="Custom Partner ledger"
          id="account.menu_account_partner_ledger"
          parent="account.next_id_22"/>
```

A better way to do it (without specifying the parent menu) is to use `record` tag:

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="account.menu_account_partner_ledger">
    <field name="name">Custom Partner ledger</field>
</record>
```

Comment: @MohammadAL-Hamalawy I am glad to help.